# Excel Advanced Filters - Filter a table with multiple cell values

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I've been grappling with this for most of the day and managed to crash Excel 2010 a few times in the process with borrowed code from the web.

I have a table (see below) with 1 column of unique values called 'ID'. I also have a list of ID's e.g. [2 5 7 8] that are a subset of those in the table. I'd like to only show the table entries that correspond to those in the subset.

I'm sure it must be possible to do but I have limited VB skills.

```
ID   A__    B ____     C _
1,   1.1,   2.1,      -2.1
2,   1.2,   2.2,      -2.1
3,   1.3,   2.3,      -2.1
4,   1.4,   2.4,      -2.1
5,   1.5,   2.5,      -2.1
6,   1.6,   2.6,      -2.1
7,   1.7,   2.7,      -2.1
8,   1.8,   2.8,      -2.1
```

Could someone suggest a solution for this?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do this in VBA.

Simply add another column and populate it with this formula: (assumption is that it starts in row 2, the ID is in column A and that your list of selected IDs is in Sheet2!A1:A10 - adjust accordingly)

```
=--NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,0)))
```

Copy this formula down. This formula will return TRUE for every line that has an ID in the list - and FALSE else. Now you only need to apply an AutoFilter and filter for TRUE - done! :-)

If you place this code in the worksheet with your selection, the autofilter will update automatically:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .Range("$A:$C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. The only issue I have with it is that if I make a change to the subset it is not immediately reflected in the AutoFiltered table, which could be disastrous. Is there a way to make the AutoFilter refresh when a change is made in that column in Sheet2 for example?

Comment: You would need to automate this with a small Sheet_Change event that reapplies the autofilter.

Comment: Got it this works when subset and table are on same sheet not occupying same rows ---- http://superuser.com/questions/249758/how-to-i-auto-refresh-an-excel-auto-filter-when-data-is-changed

Comment: great! I just update the answer in the same moment, providing a slightly different (and admittedly not so elegant) solution. :-)

Comment: Leave it there, because I don't know if what I posted works when using separate sheets. Thanks again though.